# Why nodejs console.log different output format for the same object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For the following code:

```
function F() {
}

// Define class fields for F
F.value = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

console.log('F', F); // F function F() { }

console.log(F);      // { [Function: F] value: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
```

In the code above, I have define class fields for the constructor `F`. When I `console.log()` in `node` different argument list, the printing result is different for `F`.
The one is `function F() { }`, the other is `{ [Function: F] value: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }`. So that's why?
But the output is same in browser console.
My `node` version is `v4.2.6` and `linux`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args

Comment: Thanks, @MukeshSharma, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bug. There's no good reason to differ.

Why does this happen? [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) delegates to [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) ([quite literally](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.2.6/lib/console.js#L36)), and `format` distin­guishes between a string for the first argument (that might be a format string) and something else. You can find the exact algorithm [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.2.6/lib/util.js#L13-L52). Basically:

- when the first argument is a string, placeholders get replaced by the respective values, then further arguments are adjoined. Those are [inspected](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) when they are objects or symbols, but just cast to strings and concatenated otherwise.
- when the first argument is not a string, every value is inspected, then they are concatenated together.

Due to the object check relying on `typeof`, it does not consider functions to be objects, and your function is directly [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString). This difference between casting and inspecting can also be observed for other values (e.g. `console.log("0", "example")` vs `console.log(0, "example")`).

Comment: Thank your for your great answer. This involves alogrithm of `console.log()`.  When I use `console.log()` in node, I have found some inconsistent output for the same object. So that's so strang to me. And I want to know why.